# facebook app login switch user

Tags: facebook, authentication

Facebook app login directly takes the info of the currently logged in user in the broswer. Is it possible to ask for user email and password in app login so that we can login whoever user we want ? (Don't have to be the logged in user.)

Answer (score 0):

You should never ask the user for his FB password on your own, use `FB.logout` to logout an authorized user and call `FB.login` to authorize another one. Of course this also works in a similar way with other SDKs, but the JS SDK is the recommended one.